# How to move prefixes using cut command

Tags: linux, rename

Cant seem to finish my command

The following command cuts first 10 charqacters in all filenames:

```
ls | cut -c11-
```

How do i incorporate it in a loop to rename all channels removing first 10 characters.

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" <stuck here> "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small change will work,

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" `echo $i|cut -c11-`; done
```